# PyQt4 Widgets's component names for stylesheet

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, stylesheet

I am trying to learn to create external `qss` files (stylesheets) for my python program that is written in PyQt for fancier look.

[image]

In the Qt stylesheet examples, it used this

```
 QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
 background: red;
 border: 2px outset red;
```

}

to specifi the style properties of the connerbutton(red rectangle) on `QTableWidget`. 
However, it doesn't say how the other component names should be addressed. For example, i have no idea how to change the `horizontalheaderlabel` and `verticalheader` styles.

When i use a stylesheet without using any component names (like `QTableCornerButton`) like this

```
    QTableWidget {
     selection-background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0.5, y2: 0.5,
                                 stop: 0 #579599, stop: 1 #39B4BD);
background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
stop: 0 #D1DBEB, stop: 0.4 #C0D1EB,stop: 0.5 #ABBEDB, stop: 1.0 #95ABCC);
border:1px solid #7286A3;
border-top-left-radius: 9px;
border-top-right-radius: 9px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 9px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;
padding:0px;

 }
```

It applies the style to the whole widget instead of particular areas.

Where can i find the names for the widget's components that is supported by stylesheets ( For example, `QTableCornerButton`) online?

[Qt Stylesheet example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview) is good but it does not provide all the names and properties i can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at documentation [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls)?

Comment: I don't see anything related to the table `horizontalheader` or `verticalheader`. Does that mean it is impossible to apply stylesheet directly to them? or am i missing something?

Comment: AFAIR that is done by styling QHeaderView, like this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qheaderview